# Ubuntu installer does not show any partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 20.04

Ubuntu installer did not show me the installation mode:

1. Install alongside windows
2. Something else

It directly took me to partition table,to my surprise its empty I can't see any partition.

Things I tried already :

1. Disabled secure boot and fast startup
2. set nomodeset and achi=off while booting live usb.
3. Confirmed that my SATA controller is set to AHCI already
   Model:HP 15s du3032tu

Answer (score 1):

You need unpartitioned free space in order to get the "Install Alongside Windows" option.  That means you need to use Disks or some other partition tool to prepare your disk to have a portion of the drive without a defined partition or file system.

You also need to boot the USB installation media in the same way as Windows is currently installed. For example, if Windows is a UEFI installation, you must boot the USB in UEFI mode, not BIOS or "compatibility".

Comment: Actually I am booting from USB just like windows its UEFI by default my laptop has only UEFI .The thing is in live USB when I opened 'files' app,it did not show any harddisk overall its detecting only external drives but not internal drives.

Comment: Your file manager will only show mounted file systems.  I suggest that you use the Disks application to manage partitions.

Comment: Yeah I did ,I created 100 gb free space using disk management in windows but its still the same result.

Comment: Don't use *Windows* to prepare your disk for *Ubuntu*.  I have suggested that you use the **Disks** application on the live session of Ubuntu.  The application is called **Disks** (`gnome-disk-utility`)